# Different date format in javascript on IE 9 and IE Latest Versions

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, datetime

I am getting the below string while working on IE with different versions.

In IE Latest Versions: "Mon Nov 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

In IE Version 9      : "Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014"

i am passing IE Latest Versions value to back end then converted to c# datetime object like below

```
var Startdatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate.Substring(0, 24), "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but when I am getting old browser value then I got error .
so how can I convert the old browser value and latest browser value in datetime object in c#.

Comment: How do you get that string? How do you pass the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I am passing the year from java script and in back end checking that year is same as the last 4 characters of startdate if it matches then append the year value to  1st 10th characters of startdate. 
then proceed with remain code.

```
var CheckYearinlast=startdate.Substring(startdate.Length-4);
                if (year.Equals(CheckYearinlast))
                {
                    startdate = startdate.Substring(0, 10) + " " + CheckYearinlast + " 00:00:00";
                }

                var Startdatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate.Substring(0, 24), "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `startdate.Substring(0, 24)` returns `Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC+` for your IE9 version, clearly your format and string does not match.

But I would parse [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instead of `DateTime` for your both example since you have a [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value.

```
string s = "Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'zzz yyyy", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dto))
{

}
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `10.11.2014 00:00:00 +05:30`.

Or you can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301210.aspx) which takes format as a string array so you can provide your both format and parse your string with the one is matched.